# TomCat Manager GUI not working

Tags: tomcat

I have been trying to get Manager GUI on Tomcat working,
Following is my tomcat-users.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">

<!--
  NOTE:  By default, no user is included in the "manager-gui" role required
  to operate the "/manager/html" web application.  If you wish to use this app,
  you must define such a user - the username and password are arbitrary. It is
  strongly recommended that you do NOT use one of the users in the commented out
  section below since they are intended for use with the examples web
  application.
-->
<!--
  NOTE:  The sample user and role entries below are intended for use with the
  examples web application. They are wrapped in a comment and thus are ignored
  when reading this file. If you wish to configure these users for use with the
  examples web application, do not forget to remove the <!.. ..> that surrounds
  them. You will also need to set the passwords to something appropriate.
-->
<!--
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="<must-be-changed>" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="<must-be-changed>" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="<must-be-changed>" roles="role1"/>
-->

  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <user username="guiadmin" password="guiadmin" roles="admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="guimanager" password="guimanager" roles="manager-gui"/>

</tomcat-users>
```

I am getting following error (click on link to see the image) when I click on manager app on tomcat page

[Error Page Tomcat - Manager App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLXJm.jpg)

I tried various things that I got as help here but nothing worked, can someone please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which user did you try? The user `guiadmin` has a role that isn't recognized by the `manager`. I would have expected `guimanager` to work, since it has the role `manager-gui` which is recognized. Are you even being asked for a username and password?

Comment: I forgot to add context.xml, I added the same and then the signin screen appeared. Thanks for the revert.

Comment: For me I had to allow remote access to the manager webapp: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36703856/access-tomcat-manager-app-from-different-host

Answer (score 1):

your User configuration file seems alright to me.

this problem can occur when your tomcat server deploy path isn't 'webapps' where your Tomcat Manager folder resides by default. If this is the case, setting your server deploy path to 'webapps' and redeploying your application will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you uncomment the text written in the  and  tag inside the  tag.

As you uncomment the username and password, then it will be accessed easily by Tomcat Manager Application.