# Tomcat manager access denied issue

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8.5

**I know this question asked more and more but my problem not resolved with that answers.**

I installed tomcat `8.5.15` on centos 7 with [this](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-tomcat-on-centos/)  and when browse with server IP on port 8080 it display as expected. now my problem is access to manger page. i defined user on `tomcat-users.xml` file as following:

```
 <role rolename="admin"/>
 <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
 <role rolename="manager"/>
 <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
 <user username="name" password="pass" roles="admin,admin-  gui,manager,manager-gui"/>
```

but again i can't access to manager page.

**I can add more explanation later.**

Comment: I tried placing your tomcat-users.xml entries into my local tomcat server. When I hit the URL http://localhost:8080/manager it's prompting for username/password. By entering name/pass it displays the manager page properly. Can you please let us know, what URL you are hitting and what username/password ur entering

Comment: @RajeshKumarRaj, Thanks, but i installed it on centos and want to run with server IP. `http://x.x.x.x:8080/manager/html` and `http://x.x.x.x:8080/manager`

Comment: When I tried calling by IP Address I got an issue and manager page is not getting displayed.
I can resolve this by modifying Tomcat Manager context.xml.
Please refer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36703856/access-tomcat-manager-app-from-different-host