# 403 Access Denied message - EC2 - Tomcat8

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2

So I downloaded tomcat8 on my machine and when I type the Public DNS (IPv4)
on chrome, I am getting this.

[image: image1]

My context.xml file looks like this.

[image]

I was hoping to get at least the Unauthorized message(401). So how to fix the Access Denied message?

Thanks,

Theo.

Comment: What URL are you hitting on the server?  The error seems to indicate that you're trying to use `/manager-gui` but it's possible that that's just a generic error.

Comment: @stdunbar I am hitting this url: http://ec2-35-177-67-38.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/manager/html

Comment: @stdunbar I am also starting the server from the terminal as:  sudo service tomcat8 start but still nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access Tomcat Manager App from different host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36703856/access-tomcat-manager-app-from-different-host)

Comment: Hmm. I don't have this tomcat/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml

Comment: Then the unix distribution maintainers put it somewhere else. On debian it would be `/usr/share/tomcat8-admin/manager/META-INF/context.xml` or `/etc/tomcat8/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml`