# Allow Tomcat 8.5.32 access from 1 remote computer (not all)

Tags: java, xml, tomcat

On Tomcat 8.5.32, I am trying to figure out how to format my ip in the tomcat/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml file to allow only one additional ip along with the local host. Can someone help me modify the below code taken from [Access Tomcat Manager App from different host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36703856/access-tomcat-manager-app-from-different-host) to allow a specific other machine as opposed to all the machines?

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
     allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />
```

Comment: Your example already shows that the _separator_ is the | character. Just add "|othermachineip" in the allow attribute value.

Comment: @EugèneAdell It's a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), so be sure to pay attention to proper formatting.