# Tomcat manager app: not authorized to view page

Tags: docker, tomcat, war, plesk

I try to deploy my app from Docker.
In Dockerfile:

```
  FROM tomcat:9-jre8-alpine
  ADD config/tomcat-users.xml  /usr/local/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml
  ADD config/settings.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/settings.xml
  ADD config/context.xml /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml
  ADD target/author.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
  EXPOSE 8080
  CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]
```

so, in tomcat-users.xml:

```
 <tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd
http://tomcat.apache.org/xml "
          version="1.0">

<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

in settings.xml:

```
    <servers>
          <server>
              <id>TomcatServer</id>
              <username>tomcat</username>
              <password>s3cret</password>
          </server>
      </servers>
```

and in context.xml:

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
     allow=".*" />
</Context>
```

But, trying to access Tomcat manager app remotely (domain in plesk), I have got:
"You are not authorized to view this page.By default the Manager is only accessible from a browser running on the same machine as Tomcat. If you wish to modify this restriction, you'll need to edit the Manager's context.xml file...."

Additionally: for localhost-connection its work well! The problem in remote-connection

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access Tomcat Manager App from different host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36703856/access-tomcat-manager-app-from-different-host) or [this (ServerFault): How to access tomcat manager gui from another machine?](https://serverfault.com/questions/796960/how-to-access-tomcat-manager-gui-from-another-machine)

Comment: yes, I tried that advises. In particular, replaced "llow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1"  with allow=".*" But without success

Comment: They're asking to comment the whole `<Valve />` block (effectively removing it). You may want to just be more specific in which _exact_ host you allow in addition to localhost, but in order to provide access from anywhere, the Valve-part is key. (oops, scrolled down - that was another answer that suggests removing the valve - but still: that's key)

Comment: I commented this <Valve />. And with the same result...

Comment: You'll need to find the correct file to change, there are multiple context.xml files.

Comment: I have found context.xml in 2 places: webapp/host-manager/META-INF/context.xml . and in conf/context.xml.    In first case Valve className . have been found, and I and I commented It.  But it does not work

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me:

1-get the image:

```
docker pull tomcat:9.0.46-jdk8-adoptopenjdk-openj9
```

2-create folder `d:\folder123`

3-copy `conf\tomcat-users.xml` and `\webapps\manager\META-INF\context.xml` to `d:\folder123`

4-add below to `tomcat-users.xml`

```
<role rolename="manager-gui" />
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui,manager-script" />
```

5-remove below from `context.xml`

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />
```

6-create `Dockerfile` in `d:\folder123` with this content

```
FROM tomcat:9.0.46-jdk8-adoptopenjdk-openj9
USER root
RUN mv /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ /usr/local/tomcat/webapps2/
RUN mv /usr/local/tomcat/webapps.dist/ /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
COPY tomcat-users.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/
COPY context.xml /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager/META-INF/
CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]
```

7-create new image named `amirimage1`

```
docker build -t amirimage1:1.0.0 "D:\\folder123"
```

8-run image

```
docker run --name amirtomcatcontainer1 -p 8889:8080 amirimage1:1.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the valve value in manager.xml? there was another valve stanza with the IP restriction and I have disabled it. all worked then
/conf/Catalina/localhost/

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bit late but I had the same problem. I solved it by editing the password of the user "robot" which says "must-be-changed" and not only the password of the "admin" user:

[image: all default password must be change]

I'm using tomcat 10 with docker. I was using only the user "admin" and it's a little weird that you need to change the password of the other user but in the other hand they say "must-be-changed".