# Tomcat 10 (10.1.16) how to add access to host manager app to localhost and local network but not for internet?

Tags: fedora, tomcat10

I'm using Tomcat 10 (10.1.16) and I have 2 instances of the webserver running on Fedora 39 that I installed on my Raspberry Pi 4 Mobel B.

**Tomcat instances:**

1. For home, personal projects and some Java development.
2. For internet, to expose my finished web sites and web services/APIs.

For the first instance, I want to enable access to the host manager only for localhost and local network IP's.

For the second instance, I want to enable access to the host manager only for localhost and local network IP's but I want other apps deployed there be accessible through the internet for general public.
What is the most secure way to achieve this without compromising performance?

**What I know and did so far:**

On both instances I just commented the "Valve" tag on the file $TOMCAT_INSTANCE/webapps/host-manager/META-INF/context.xml

```
<!-- <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" /> -->
```

But this leaves both instances completly exposed and accessible to local traffic and internet traffic.

I understand that I need to change the allow attribute in the Valve tag but I'm not very good with regular expressions.

Also am I following the best practises on how my system is structured? I would appreciate some guidelines or feedback.

How I structured the instances on Linux:

**Users:**

**root:** Holds the Tomcat bin and lib folder. As specified here: [Tomcat - CATALINA_BASE and CATALINA_HOME variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090398/tomcat-catalina-base-and-catalina-home-variables)

**userhome:** ENV variables that point to root $CATALINA_HOME. No sudo privileges. No port redirect on the router.

**userprod:** ENV variables that point to root $CATALINA_HOME. No sudo privileges. Router port redirect from external 80 to internal 9090.

On Fedora firewalld port 8080 is open for local TCP traffic (source: 192.168.1.0/24). Port 9090 is open for TCP traffic from any source.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a possible solution that works.

On the second instance, I changed the name of the **index.jsp** file on the folder $TOMCAT_INSTANCE/webapps/ROOT/index.jsp so it won't be acessible to anyone on the internet.

On the manager and host-manager apps I removed the commented tag and changed the Valve to allow local network traffic (**|192\.168\.1\.\d+**).

**Files changed:**

$TOMCAT_INSTANCE/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml

$TOMCAT_INSTANCE/webapps/host-manager/META-INF/context.xml

The Valve on both apps now looks like this:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
     allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1|192\.168\.1\.\d+" />
```

Restarted the Tomcat server and now it works as expected.

I found this solution on a comment here: [Access Tomcat Manager App from different host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36703856/access-tomcat-manager-app-from-different-host)

Hope this helps someone with a similar configuration problem.